# Of or pertaining to algebraic geometry

Tags: expressions, compound-adjectives

Mathematicians do this one way, but I'd like the opinion of the ELU community: how do you turn algebraic geometry into an adjective phrase?

Mathematicians say

> We solved the problem using algebro-geometric methods.

In this particular case, which is not the best example, you could also say

> We solved the problem using algebraic geometry methods.

Something logical but not really very good is

> We solved the problem using algebraically geometric methods.

Is algebro-geometric the best of these? Notice "using algebraic geometry methods" doesn't work for some phrases, but I don't have an example off the top of my head.

Comment: The form ***algebro*** isn't actually in the full OED. So far as I can tell, [it's "borrowed" from Esperanto.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/algebro) I can't see any reason why mathematicians couldn't have just used a couple of consecutive "noun adjuncts", and talked about ***algebra geometry solutions***. But so long as they all agree what they mean, they can use whatever "words" they like.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suspect that it's analogous to "integro-differential equations." Mathematicians sometimes have novel ways of naming things: Dirac forming "bra" and "ket" operators out of "bracket", for example.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/algebrogeometric) actually lists the term 'algebrogeometric', defining it as 'pertaining to algebraic geometry' (a compound noun it also defines), rather than 'pertaing to algebra and/or geometry'.

Comment: As a mathematician you should be able to consider *algebraic geometric methods* as employing a monoid. The crux is, monoids are commutative, so it'd be identical with *geometric algebraic*, but *Geometric Algebra* exists as quite a different beast, so a commutative join operation is not a sound solution to your problem.

Comment: As a rule, combined specialties with names like _algebraic geometry, tensor analysis,_ or _point-set topology_ get frozen into noun compounds and simply modify without benefit of (more) morphology, as in _an algebraic geometry solution_ or _a point-set topology theorem_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I guess the issue is when it's an adverb rather than an adjective. Not sure if I should edit my question. It would be something like "We algebro-geometrically analyze..."

Comment: Do mathematicians really say "algebro-geometric"? That's very odd morphology. There's no _O_ there to show up in the combining form. I should ask the algebraic geometers I know.

Comment: @JohnLawler I always thought it was odd too, but I could come up with no better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

John Lawler pointed me to this discussion, not so much because I'm a former linguistics professor, but because my husband is a mathematician whose area of specialization is algebraic geometry.  He read this thread and said: never. He would never use any of the alternates suggested here. The sentence he gave me as an example of normal usage is 'they used algebraic geometry methods' and he made a horrified face at 'algebro-'.

Comment: I never edited my question, but I really meant as an adverb. How would he modify a verb using algebraic geometry? We can't say "We algebraic geometry analyze the problem." I've always seen "We algebro-geometrically analyze the problem."

Comment: He says he would rewrite the sentence in order to avoid the problem. 'We solved the problem using algebraic geometry methods.'   Where did you see this usage?

Comment: I've seen it in several papers. Here's an example: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11424-019-8348-0

Comment: I'll ask him to look at the link.